# Update two records of one type when a single record is triggered

Tags: collection, read-only

I have two opportunities. When I update a single opportunity, based on that I have to pull one more opportunity based on some criteria and update both of them. But as I'm updating through trigger, I'm unable to find a way to update second record. Because, the before trigger will not let me call update operation and I can't update the newMap with second record. When I tried doing that, it threw "Collection is read-only" error.

Comment: One option would be to query for the 2nd record and update it in an @future method or move the trigger to an after update where you could update both of them at the same time.

Comment: ^ should be the answer

Comment: @crmprogdev I chose to go with after trigger. As my requirement is based on a visualforce page, i can't rely on future call. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your description, I believe you have two options. One option would be to query for the 2nd record and update it in an @future method. The 2nd option would be to change the trigger to an AfterUpdate trigger where you could update both of the records at the same time (query for the 2nd record & add it to your list).

Comment: I chose to go with after trigger. As my requirement is based on a visualforce page, i can't rely on future call. Thank you.